# Size of an DatagramPacket

Tags: java, arrays, network-programming

So I just red this snippet of code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{ 
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(1500);
    while(true){
        byte[] recieveData = null; //<---look at this #############!!!
        DatagramPaket recievePaket = new DatagramPacket (recieveData, recieveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(recievePaket);
        String text = recieveData.toString();
        if (text.equals("exit")){
            serverSocket.close();
            System.exit(42);
        }else if (text.equals("scan")){
            scan();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know that  the DatagramPacket needs a buffer but how can it by initialized with "null" ? It made any sense to me if one would not want to store the data that was received but how can one then see if "exit" or "scan" was sent?
On top, how can anyone know the size which the buffer needs to be anyway before no packet was received?

Comment: `recieveData.length` is a field of null, are you sure that code works? I tried it and it did not, giving a NullPointer at the expected place

Comment: no I'm not sure it works, the question is basically how to do it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT_NUMBER)) {
      boolean loop = true;
      final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
      final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
      while (loop) {
        socket.receive(packet);
        final String text = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
        switch (text) {
          case "exit":
            loop = false;
            break;
          case "scan":
            scan();
            break;
          default:
            System.err.printf("Received unknown command `%s`%n", text);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately you have to set the buffer size.

The changes I made included:

- Adding the buffer size

  - Needed as you have to create a buffer to put the data into
- Adding trim() to remove newlines so that  netcat can send commands.

  - Needed as `exit\n` does not equal `exit`
- Using switch to clean up command routing

  - Makes the code a little easier to read
- Using a condition and try with resources rather than an infinite loop

  - Avoids issues, and ensures the socket is always closed on exit
- Adding finals to make code easier to reason about

  - Makes it obvious which variables never change value
- Renaming some variables to names that explained what they are for

  - Just cleanup to allow IntelliJ to show the real issues
- Fixing minor typos that stopped compilation

  - Tested with nc on Ubuntu, so needed to compile

Comment: Great answer! Let ma ask a few questions regarding your answer: Can BUFFER_SIZE be set to 4 bytes since we only expect to receive the commands "scan" and "exit"? (would automatically discard newline on top). And, presupposed we want to run this as an infinite loop and receive "scan" as often as wished, is it still possible to declare the variables as final (dont think so, right?)

Comment: Can do, the trim does help show short bad commands like `foo` though, the loop can run multiple times, final just makes sure the variable is not changed while it is in scope